# Linked MySQL Server Hanging on Insert

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008

I'm running a task every 5 minutes on MS SQL Server 2008 that links to MySQL on another server in the network. It works probably 80% of the time. The remaining 20% results in MySQL hanging, and a `service mysql restart` is required.

Here's some info on the query that runs every 5 minutes:

- ~32,000 rows and 25 columns
- Engine = MyISAM
- query (ran from SQL Server 2008) = `INSERT INTO MYSQLINTRANET...segments_temp SELECT * FROM ProjectTracking.dbo.segments;`
- Row failure appears to be random
- Error logs are empty

Is it possible that the `ProjectTracking.dbo.segments` could be locked resulting in a hang?

Without any reported errors in the error log, where can I go from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd have left this as a comment but I want to quote some code, so I'm doing it here instead.  I'd start with trying to track down where the lock is happening.  The next time you've got a lock, gather some data.  On the MS SQL server run the following:

```
USE master
select text,wait_time,blocking_session_id AS "Block",
percent_complete, * from sys.dm_exec_requests 
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle)  AS s2 order by start_time asc
```

Analyze the return and see what the status is.  Is it blocked?  Is it waiting on data to return from remote?

On the mySQL server run:

```
show full processlist;
```

As well as:

```
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS
```

The first will list the running processes, what is the status of your query?  What does it say it's waiting on.  The second will help you find if you're having a deadlock issue.

Comment: Thanks for the response - I'll run those tonight when everyone leaves